# CURL Post adds headers to uploaded file data

Tags: php, post, curl, upload, header

i am kinda new to PHP so i require some help here.

I have a Java Servlet running on Tomcat 7 which exposes an API that receives a Wav file. What i do in the Servlet is get the data from request.getInputStream(); and save it to a file.

Using fiddler i would call the API (with this in the request body <@INCLUDE *C:\wavlocation\2.wav*@>) and it would save the file correctly. now i have a script in PHP which calls this API using curl but for some reason it adds more information to the data (input stream of the body).

here is how the correct Wav file looks like in text editor:

```
RIFFd¯ WAVEfmt      @¬  €>  [1]  data@¯ çÿ×ÿïÿ÷ÿÿÿ ÿÿ÷ÿÿÿ ÿÿïÿ ' 7 7 _ ? /  ÿÿ…
```

here is how the wav file is saved from my servlet:

```
------------------------------4564fc26ec61
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_box"; filename="/var/www/recordings/1ab26427-0b9e-428e-8730-9fd6076c52e7.wav"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

RIFFd¯ WAVEfmt      @¬  €>  [1]  data@¯ çÿ×ÿïÿ÷ÿÿÿ ÿÿ÷ÿÿÿ ÿÿïÿ ' 7 7 _ ? /  ÿÿ¬…
```

as you can see for some reason the PHP curl adds more information to the data which i do not require. i just want to save the data of the wav file.

Please assist me guys :) thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By the look of this, and due to your lack of details (like there's no code shoing what you did or what the exact requirements of API are), it seems like you're doing am multipart formpost while the server-end expects you to send a more "pure" POSt without the multipart stuff.

But really, if you would tell us more details we could answer with more certainty.